# Excel Pivot table error 1004 when create the pivot

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table, I found some code and I try to change it for my need, I take the error “1004”  Application-defined or Object-defined error when I run the code, can anyone help?

```
 Sub SalesNew()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim BACKORDER, Analysis As Workbook
 Set BACKORDER = Workbooks("BACKORDER2019.xlsx")
 Set Analysis = Workbooks("Analysis.xlsx")

 Dim wsBACK As Worksheet
 Set wsBACK = BACKORDER.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Dim RngBACKstart, RngBACKend, RngBACKnew  As Range
 Set RngBACKstart = wsBACK.Range("G4")
 Set RngBACKend = wsBACK.Cells(wsBACK.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)
 Set RngBACKnew = Range(RngBACKstart, RngBACKend)

 With RngBACKnew
 .NumberFormat = "General"
 .Value = .Value
 End With

  With BACKORDER
    Sheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Pivot"
  End With

  Dim PSheet As Worksheet
  Set PSheet = BACKORDER.Worksheets("Pivot")
  Dim PCache As PivotCache
  Dim PTable As PivotTable
  Dim PRange As Range
  Dim FirstRow As Range
  Dim LastCol As Range

  Set FirstCell = wsBACK.Range("A3")
  Set LastCell = wsBACK.Cells(wsBACK.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
  Set PRange = Range(FirstCell, LastCell)

   Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
  (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
   CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
   TableName:="SalesPivotTable")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     End Sub
```

Comment: You should tell us which line errors.

Comment: Yes, sorry. When the code run the Set PCache....

Comment: Note - perhaps a different error, but from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create): When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly. This is for `SourceData`.

Comment: Have a look at the first section here https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables I think you need to create the cache and then the table (though not sure as rarely do PTs in VBA).